# Select mysql de um ranking

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Bom estou montando um ranking de doações, a tabela no banco de dados está assim:

```
    --
-- Estrutura da tabela `Doacoes`
--

CREATE TABLE `Doacoes` (
`Cod` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Doador` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`Data` datetime NOT NULL,
`Valor` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `Doacoes`
--

INSERT INTO `Doacoes` (`Cod`, `Doador`, `Data`, `Valor`) VALUES
(100, 'Hugo Borges', '2019-11-28 00:00:00', '10.00'),
(101, 'Hugo Borges', '2019-11-28 00:00:00', '10.00'),
(102, 'Rafael', '2019-11-28 00:00:00', '30.00');
```

Bom estou montando um select que vai me dar os 10 maiores doadores. Porém note que tenho que unir os nome iguais, somar o total da doação e exibir a data da última doação.

Alguém pode me dar uma mão com isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hugo,

Para somar os valores, você utiliza o `SUM` do SQL.

Para trazer a última data, você pode utilizar o `MAX` do SQL.

Para limitar a dez registros, você pode utilizar o `LIMIT` do MySQL.

E por fim, para unir os nomes, na query, você faz o `GROUP BY` do SQL pelo campo de *Doador*.

---

Veja um exemplo dessa query:

```
SELECT SUM(Valor) Valor
     , Doador
     , MAX(Data) data
  FROM Doacoes
 GROUP BY Doador
 LIMIT 10;
```

> Veja no fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b849030/3

Comment: Show, muito obrigado

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT Doador,
       SUM(Valor) as TotalDoado,
       MAX(Data) as UltimaDoacao
  FROM Doacoes
 GROUP BY Doador
 LIMIT 10;
```